# using preg_match with html comments

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to convert into a string the html contained between these comments

```
<!--content-start-->
 desired html
<!--content-end-->
```

so I use pregmatch, right?

```
preg_match("/<!--content-start-->(.*)<!--content-end-->/i", $rss, $content);
```

but it wont work. Maybe a problem with the REGEX?

Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. You use an HTML parser!

Comment: for example please?

Comment: @miken32 Although, arguably, they aren't "parsing HTML". They are simply extracting one block of text between two unique tokens (regardless of content-type). Using an HTML parser in this particular example (a simple one-off pattern matching exercise) is overkill IMO. (Only a small tweak to the OPs regex is required.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a `/s` modifier will help. Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters,
> including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to
> Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character,
> independent of the setting of this modifier.

Comment: Yes, this is all that's required in the OPs example. Parsing the HTML (as mentioned in the other answer) is overkill IMO - for what is really just a simple pattern matching exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. The XPath query looks for a comment containing "content-start" and then returns the sibling nodes following it. We loop through until we find the closing comment.

```
$html = <<< HTML
<!--content-start-->
<p>Here is my <i>desired html</i></p>
<!-- a comment -->
<div class="foo">Here is more</div>
<!--content-end-->
<p>Not returning this</p>
HTML;
$return = "";
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$siblings = $xpath->query("//comment()[.='content-start']/following-sibling::node()");
foreach ($siblings as $node) {
    if ($node instanceof DOMComment && $node->textContent === "content-end") {
        break;
    }
    $return .= $dom->saveHTML($node) . "\n";
}
echo $return;
```

Output:

```
<p>Here is my <i>desired html</i></p>
<!-- a comment -->
<div class="foo">Here is more</div>
```

Comment: It's HTML, it doesn't matter where it's from.

Comment: great, I will try it. Thanks

Comment: sorry but I got these warnings: DOMDocument::loadHTML() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given 

Warning: DOMXPath::query() [domxpath.query]: Invalid or inclomplete context 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Are you kidding me? PHP 5.3 has been EOL for 5 years now. You gotta upgrade!

Comment: So its a php version problem? Sorry but its my provider the only one who can upgrade.

Comment: Yes, the second parameter has been available since PHP version 5.4.0, released in 2012. Seriously, whatever "provider" you're dealing with, if that's the sort of environment they're somehow forcing you to use, run from them as fast as you can.

Comment: Yes, but that's just trading one outdated version for a slightly less outdated one. PHP version 7.0 is out of support next week. You should be looking at 7.1 as a minimum.

Comment: Wow, thats gonna be a hell of an upgrade. I just hope my whole site wont fall apart after that.

Comment: Honestly there isn't a huge amount that breaks, most changes are new features. But start here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php

Comment: Thank you for all the advice.